# How are greetings in 18th century done?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

So I'm writing a book and I was wondering how are the above question usually done in 18cen way. A brief greeting maybe old time friends or to a noble. Yea I agree this question can be a little vast. But I'm not asking for every response ever made. How would they greet a -friend
-noble
-parents
-stranger (no need for you to go into a character just tell me how you would say it, in 18 cen of course)
What words would they typically used? Or don't use?
Here a part of my story:

Aviana turn around with something on her face that one may think she just ate something bitter but in actuality she was trying to smile. When she realized that it was one of her childhood friend her face and mood instantly flipped, smiling from ear to ear. She replied "I'm well, thank you coming". They greeted each other with hugs and kisses "you look splendid as ever today" miss rosewood said excitedly, she was right Aviana is the most stunning woman there.

How do I even?(begin)
Yes there are some grammatical errors.please let me know if you need some more clarification?

Comment: Should you be asking writing questions on [writing.se]?

Comment: Everything would depend on the relevant differences in class, station, wealth, and adherence to customs, which were complex, especially among the wealthy, who had time to indulge them.

Comment: If you are writing a novel in English, you need to study the language a lot more! For a start, your use of tenses is completely chaotic. To learn 18th century speech patterns, _read_ as much literature of the period as you can.

Comment: John lawyer. Your right, (yes there the wealth kinds). Kate bunting I think your also right, I'd need to study the language but there only do much I can learn from books